# solid line in bar plot using postaction

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, overleaf, bar-chart

I'm using overleaf. I want **solid** `north east lines` in bar plot. Used the following MWE which gives a dashed pattern. Also tried `dash pattern=on 5pt off 0pt` no changes. Any help?

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.text,patterns}

\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{006837}
\definecolor{color2}{HTML}{31a354}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5},
xlabel=abc,
}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel=xxyz,
ybar stacked,]
\addplot [fill=color2,draw=none,area legend,
    postaction={pattern=north east lines},] 
    coordinates {%{rgb:red,1;green,1;yellow,2.5}
        ({1},10)
        ({2},19)
        ({3},29)
        ({4},39)
        ({5},45)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image: Plot]

Comment: This problem only occurs on overleaf, since with MikTeX the rendering is perfect. Write to the Overleaf managers and ask them to update their distribution.

Comment: Oohhh... Thanks.

Comment: (Tom from Overleaf Support here.) Sorry for having missed this discussion: Overleaf relies on the PDF.js viewer, and unfortunately this isn't in our control, as the issue is also manifested in the PDF.js test viewer at https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

The downloaded PDF shouldn't show this issue though when viewed in your local viewer or when printed. Sorry for this limitation.